# connect HBase via java jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, hbase

I have a problem. I want to connect to hbase with java. I found some things about connecting to java, as datanocleos. I want to connect with java jdbc but I think there is not any hbase jdbc driver.
can anyone know how to do it? help me please..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is what you need

https://github.com/forcedotcom/phoenix

Phoenix: A SQL skin over HBase
'We put the SQL back in NoSQL'
Phoenix is a SQL skin over HBase, delivered as a client-embedded JDBC driver, powering the HBase use cases at Salesforce.com. Phoenix targets low-latency queries (milliseconds), as opposed to batch operation via map/reduce. To see what's supported, go to our language reference guide, read more on our wiki, and download it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use 3rd party clients like Playorm which has just started supporting Hbase. Visit http://buffalosw.com/products/playorm/

Comment: Nice idea but not much activity in past year - and only activity is to add updated CQL driver.