# What is the difference between JDBC and a Java API?

Tags: java, hbase

I'm learning about HBase, which is written in Java and therefore has a Java API.  I assumed it also supported JDBC but it looks like it doesn't, and now I'm thinking I don't really understand what JDBC means.

What is the difference?  What can I do with a Java API that I can't do with JDBC and vice versa?

Comment: JDBC _is_ a Java API for connecting to various types of RDBMS.  API stands for "application programming interface."  JDBC is definitely one of these, and so is HBase.

Comment: JDBC is a database connectivity API which is available within the default Java libraries.  It's primarily concerned with providing a common access layer into SQL based databases

Comment: Have a look here for an answer to how you can connect to HBase using a JDBC driver: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201278/connect-hbase-via-java-jdbc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a design choice. Extract from HBase presentation : *Use Apache HBase™ when you need random, realtime read/write access to your Big Data. This project's goal is the hosting of very large tables -- billions of rows X millions of columns -- atop clusters of commodity hardware. Apache HBase is an open-source, distributed, versioned, non-relational database ...*

So the creators of the project focused on **their** concern (BigData) and provided an API that does not directly support SQL, but is intended to be efficient in BigData context.

Accessing HBase through a JDBC driver is indeed possible, but is another project : [Apache Phoenix](https://phoenix.apache.org/) : *Apache Phoenix is a relational database layer over HBase delivered as a client-embedded JDBC driver targeting low latency queries over HBase data. Apache Phoenix takes your SQL query, compiles it into a series of HBase scans, and orchestrates the running of those scans to produce regular JDBC result sets.*

For reference, JDBC is a standard API that allows access to a database through SQL language in a database independant way. In that sense, JDBS is **a** Java API, but database authors can provide other Java API ...

Answer (score 0):

JDBC is the standard API for access to relational database supporting SQL, like MySQL, Oracle, H2 ...

HBase is not a Relational Database and doesn't support SQL for queries, so it can't implement JDBC. It has a custom API to access it with Java called *Java API* inside HBase docs.

Comment: The datasource for JDBC  does *not* have to be relational. In fact there are many JDBC drivers for non-relational data sources. From the Javadoc for `java.sql`: "Provides the API for accessing and processing data stored in a data source **(usually a relational database)** using the JavaTM programming language." [emphasis added]

Comment: And HBase can be accessed using a JDBC driver. See here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201278/connect-hbase-via-java-jdbc

Comment: Right, but HBase doesn't implement JDBC : http://java.dzone.com/articles/handling-big-data-hbase-part-4

Comment: That's not really relevant right, whether the JDBC driver is in the same deliverable or not? Fact is that HBase can be accessed using JDBC; almost any system can. But what the OP asked is: "What is the difference? What can I do with a Java API that I can't do with JDBC and vice versa?" I think you should expand on that in your answer.